# Error: incorrect number of dimensions & How to make an object that is the sum of the 5th column of the matrix contained in the object "myList"

Tags: r, matrix, sum

I am new to coding and I am having problems with the hw question (part 1.3): "make an object called 'ans2' that is the sum of the 5th column of the matrix contained in "myList"", because I keep getting different variations of errors whenever i try to run it
The question also specifically states: *Use `[]`, `[[]]`, `[,]` notation to answer this part

first for context this is my work for the previous parts of this problem which all ran without error:

```
#1.1
myList <- c(1:10)  
matrix(c(1:25), byrow = TRUE, nrow=5, ) 
list( str = "latte", vec = "taco", "nan", vec = c(1:7)) #question was Make an object called `myList` that contains the following elements (in order):The integers 1 through 10
*  A matrix with the integers 1 through 25 that has five rows, filled by row
*  A list that contains

      -  The text "latte"
      -  A vector with the text "taco" and "nan"
      -  A vector with the integers 1 through 7
 #1.2     
ans1 <- myList[4] #this question was: Make an object called `ans1` that is the fourth row of the matrix contained in `myList`
```

I tried doing this for this question:

```
ans2 <- colSums(myList[,c(5)], na.rm=TRUE )
```

But I got the error:
Error in myList[ , c(5)] : incorrect number of dimensions

Then I looked on some of the exchanges on this site and tried,

```
ans2 <- myList[1:nrow(myList),5]
```

But I got another new error:
Error in 1:nrow(myList) : argument of length 0

Would really appreciate help on how to solve this problem!

Comment: The matrix is the 2nd list member so try `sum(myList[[2]][, 5])`. This extracts the 2nd list member `myList[[@]]`) which is a matrix, then extracts the 5th column from that object, then sums the column's elements.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). And sorry, typo: `myList[[@]]` should be `myList[[2]]`